# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_jwt' (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi3

I can't import correct Firebase package in Raspberry PI.

```
My code:
from firebase import firebase
db = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/", None)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datastorage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
firebase/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import python_jwt as jwt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_jwt'
```

I tried to use this commands and it didn't help:

```
sudo pip install requests
sudo pip install python-firebase
pip install jwt
```

I use Python 3.7.3 and Raspbian Buster. All works on my PC but not on RPi 3B+.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I used advice from @naive.

> pip install python_jwt

After that I solved another errors in that order:

```
pip install gcloud
pip install sseclient
pip install pycrypto
pip install requests-toolbelt
```

And now I see that It works. Problem was solved.

Comment: In my case, I installed `pycryptodome` instead of `pycrypto` in windows10.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need  `python_jwt` instead of `jwt`. You can do:

`pip install python_jwt`

Comment: What errors did you get? Can you post them here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to this library:
https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Then you need to install like this:
`pip install PyJWT`

And afterwards this will work:
`import jwt`